# java method takes a T extends Number

Tags: java, generics

I am a bit rusty and got stuck on sort of elementary problem. I want my method `printBinary` to take in a `Long` or `Integer`. and base on the input type I want to call the respective Object's `toBinaryString()` method.

Now I know there are alternative ways like method overload, I can probably create two methods both call `printBinary` but one takes `Long` and the other takes `Integer`. But if I want to do this in one method how can I achieve that?

```
public static <T extends Object> void print(T arg){
    System.out.println(arg);
}

public static <T extends Number> void printBinary(T arg){
    if(arg instanceof Long){
        print(Long.toBinaryString(arg)); //this throws an error incompatible types: Number cannot be converted to long

    }else{
        print(Integer.toBinaryString(arg)); //this throws an error incompatible types: Number cannot be converted to int

    }
}
```

Comment: Use `arg.longValue()` if you want to get a `long` from your `Number`.

Comment: there's no need to do `<T extends Object>` just `T` would suffice or just `public static void print(Object arg){...`

Comment: @khelwood interesting, but even if `arg.longValue()` extracts `long` from `Number` but I still won't know which `toBinaryString()` I should call

Comment: Is there a problem just using `Long.toBinaryString(arg.longValue())` ?

Comment: If you want to limit argument types of your method to only specific subtypes like in your case `Integer` and `Long` which extend `Number`, but not `Double` which also extends Number one way could be overloading your method for precisely those two classes: `printBinary(Integer number){..}` `printBinary(Long number){..}`. It may feel like breaking the rule where we shouldn't repeat our code but here it saves us from `instanceof` and potential casting (both those mechanisms mean that there is something wrong with our OOP aspect of our project and that it probably should be redesigned).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Explanation

Your write

```
public static <T extends Number> void printBinary(T arg)
```

so you declared `T` to be something which extends `Number`. Very important, note that nothing more is known about `T`. So you can only safely assume it is `Number` but nothing more (without checking, for example using `instanceof`).

The next thing is that you write

```
// requires long
print(Long.toBinaryString(arg));
// requires int
print(Integer.toBinaryString(arg));
```

but both methods don't require `Number`, they require `long` and `int`. Take a look at their documentation ([Long](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toBinaryString-long-), [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString-int-)).

Even if we consider boxing, Java would only be able to convert `Long` into `long` and `Integer` into `int` (or vice versa). But not `Number` to `Long` or `Number` to `Integer`. A `Number` is not necessarily a `Long` or `Integer`. It could, for example, also be a `Double`. And you don't know what `T` is, you only know it is at least of type `Number`.

---

### Utility method

So what you will need to do is **explicitly** convert the `arg` to `long` and `int`. Therefore you can use utility methods provided by `Number`, namely [Number#longValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#longValue--) and [Number#intValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#intValue--):

```
print(Long.toBinaryString(arg.longValue()));
print(Integer.toBinaryString(arg.intValue()));
```

---

### Cast after `instanceof`

The other possibly is to **cast** them. As you have checked with `instanceof` that `T` truly is of type `Long` or `Integer` you can safely cast it:

```
print(Long.toBinaryString((Long) arg));
print(Integer.toBinaryString((Integer) arg));
```

After the cast Java will automatically convert `Long` to `long` and `Integer` to `int`, this is called **unboxing**. Or to make it more explicit, call the unboxing method by yourself:

```
print(Long.toBinaryString(((Long) arg).longValue()));
print(Integer.toBinaryString(((Integer) arg).intValue()));
```

---

### Notes

To be precise the cast to `Integer` is **unchecked** with your current code. You need to also check `arg instanceof Integer`, safer would thus be:

```
if (arg instanceof Long) {
    // Cast to Long is safe
} else if (arg instanceof Integer) {
    // Cast to Integer is safe
} else {
    // Neither Long nor Integer, for example Double
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only Long and Integer supported.");
}
```

Comment: bravo. `arg.longValue()` and `arg.intValue()` is exactly I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your method

```
public static <T extends Number> void printBinary(T arg){
    if(arg instanceof Long){
        print(Long.toBinaryString(arg)); //this throws an error incompatible types: Number cannot be converted to long

    }else{
        print(Integer.toBinaryString(arg)); //this throws an error incompatible types: Number cannot be converted to int

    }
}
```

to work, you need put casts when calling toBinaryString(art) method, for example like this

```
public static <T extends Number> void printBinary(T arg){
    if(arg instanceof Long){
        print(Long.toBinaryString((Long) arg)); //this throws an error incompatible types: Number cannot be converted to long

    }else{
        print(Integer.toBinaryString((Integer) arg)); //this throws an error incompatible types: Number cannot be converted to int

    }
}
```

But still, there is one problem with the code that you posted. As it was said by @Jacob H, declaration like `<T extends Number>` means that method will accept parameters of any class that extends the Number class. So it will work if parameter will be of type Integer or Long, but will fail when for example Float value will be passed. 
Unfortunately toBinaryString method is not implemented by Number class, but is a method provided by subclasses like Integer and Long. 
So for your case, it would be probably better to implement two separated methods that take parameters of different types - Long and Integer. 
In case you really want to use this generic notation, but not handle input of other types than Integer and Long, you will probably need to itroduce some kind of parameter type validation. But still, definition of method that takes Number type parameter and does not handle some of it's subclasses and some does might be confusing and will look like a bad design.

Comment: plus one. also good answer but I prefer to avoid casting and use `arg.longValue()` and `arg.intValue()`

Comment: You are right, for my point of view, in the most cases casting clearly shows, that something could be designed an a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to use `<Number>`, `<T extends Number>` means "some type T that extends Number", so it expects either Long or Integer, but not both. `<Number>` means "Number, or any type extending Number"

Comment: just use `<Number>`? so change my method signature to `public static void printBinary(Number arg)` ?

Comment: Exactly. You should also check the type in each scenario (not just if Long ... else) because [other classes than Integer and Long also use Number](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html)

Comment: @JacobH there's only two classes that have the method `toBinaryString` that's `Long` and `Integer`

Comment: @Aominè then the else clause should be empty at least. If someone tries to pass a Float this will break.

Comment: @JacobH agreed, `else if` should be utilised here. in fact, there's no need to even make this method generic. method overloading would be best here as only `Integer` and `Long` have the said method.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use method overload. Using `Number`, the method will also accept doubles.

If you really want to use `Number`, you don't need generics. Rewrite the methods like this

```
public static void print(Object arg)

public static void printBinary(Number arg)
```